# Subselects only support the COLUMNS axis

Tags: mdx, msbi

Subselects only support the COLUMNS axis.

```
SELECT  NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[Total Due] } ON COLUMNS,
TopCount ({[Store].[Name].Members *[Customer].[Store ID 1].Members }
,5,
[Measures].[Total Due]) ON ROWS
FROM [TOP_5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Subselects support as many axes as you like - in fact the subselect is one of the occasions where you can practically use more than two axes.

```
SELECT 
  [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Region].MEMBERS ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM 
( //<< subselect starts here
  SELECT 
    [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Region].[Canada] ON 0
   ,[Product].[Product].[Mountain-200 Black, 42] ON 1
   ,[Promotion].[Promotion Type].[No Discount] ON 2
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].[CY 2008] ON 3
  FROM [Adventure Works]
) //<< subselect ends here
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount];
```

Did you try the WITH clause

```
WITH SET [X] AS
  TopCount (
     {[Store].[Name].Members *[Customer].[Store ID 1].Members }
     ,5
     ,[Measures].[Total Due]
  ) 
SELECT  
   NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[Total Due] } ON COLUMNS,
   [X] ON ROWS
FROM [TOP_5];
```

Comment: Hello, I want to Top 5 count using multidimensional but I am getting error *Subselects only support the COLUMNS axis* Fo this MDX query SELECT  NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[Total Due] } ON COLUMNS,
TopCount ({[Store].[Name].Members *[Customer].[Store ID 1].Members }
,5,
[Measures].[Total Due]) ON ROWS
FROM [TOP_5]